# PHP: How to convert smart quotes to normal quotes when regex matching?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a small piece of code that searches a string for a pattern of `<quote>text<quote>` - The idea here being to find quotes within a string.

Currently I have this as the preg_match function

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $essay, $q);
```

However I have found that when pasting in text from word processors or PDFs - the quotation mark becomes `“ ”` a rich text format quotation mark.

How could you go about filtering these out and converting them back to plain text quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) function to convert these `smart quotes` to normal quotes, like this:

```
$essay = str_replace(array('“','”'), '"', $essay);
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $essay, $q);
```